# fix the broken packages: Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management

how to fix the broken packages? I am trying to install GMT v5 on Ubuntu 16.04. When I run following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install subversion libgdal1-dev   
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I tried removing the locks using following commands

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

but it did not work fo rme.

I also used synaptic manager to download the required library but it asks me to fix the broken packages first.

Comment: This is not about broken packages. At the same time you run the command, some process is doing the same. So, the package manager system keep it locked to prevent confict. Usually you should be able to run the command after few minutes.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

You can list broken packages :

```
dpkg -l | grep ^..r
```

**r** state (on the third field) means: reinst-required (package broken, re-installation required)